# K8s doesn't mount files on Persistent Volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a Docker image and I'd like to share an entire directory on a volume (a Persistent Volume) on Kubernetes.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /node-test
COPY hello.md /node-test/hello.md
VOLUME /node-test
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Basically it copies a file `hello.md` and makes it part of the image (lets call it `my-image`).

On the Kubernetes deployment config I create a container from `my-image` and I share a specific directory to a volume.

#### Kubernetes deployment

```
# ...
 spec:
    containers:
    - image: my-user/my-image:v0.0.1
      name: node
      volumeMounts:
      - name: node-volume
        mountPath: /node-test
    volumes:
    - name: node-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: node-volume-claim
```

I'd expect to see the `hello.md` file in the directory of the persistent volume, but nothing shows up.

If I don't bind the container to a volume I can see the `hello.md` file (with `kubectl exec -it my-container bash`).

I'm not doing anything different from what this [official Kubernetes example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/) does. As matter of fact I can change `mountPath` and switch to the official Wordpress image and it works as expected.

How can [Wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) copy all  files into the volume directory?

What's in the Wordpress Dockerfile that is missing on mine?

Comment: Hi, you need to use subPATH in order to keep the content in the directory https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

Comment: ```
      volumeMounts:
      -  name: node-volume
        mountPath: /node-test
        subPath: node-test

```

Comment: @a.barbieri have you by any chance resolved or understood this "inconsistency"? Pretty new here on the kubernetes topic, I'm really confused at the moment because I would have expected the volumes to work like for "docker volumes", while here it actually seems that even by creating persistent volumes on reboot the data is lost.
I've tried with subpaths and they work "on startup", but if I make changes and then recreate the POD the changes are overwritten. (continue...)

Comment: The only thing I've found is to use the init container but I find it quite cumbersome and I have to modify the dockerfile (at least the directories where to write the data).
Have you discovered anything in this long period?
If so, is it possible to contact you in any way?
Thanks. Ciao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to overwrite the existing files/content, you can use subpath to mount the testdir directory (In the example below)   in the existing Container file system.

```
 volumeMounts:
  - name: node-volume
    mountPath: /node-test/testdir
    subPath: testdir
volumes:
- name: node-volume
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: node-volume-claim
```

you can find for more information here [using-subpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

Comment: It actually copies the directory, but I cannot find files in it. :-(

Comment: The [Helm stable/wordpress chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/wordpress/templates/deployment.yaml#L166-L179) does exactly what you said, so it must right. I'll do some more research