# How to merge data from docker image with kubernetes volume (NFS)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, volume, nfs

I have a docker image that contains data in directors /opt/myfiles, Lets say the following:
/opt/myfiles/file1.txt
/opt/myfiles/file2.dat

I want to deploy that image to kubernetes and mount an NFS volume to that directory so that the changes to these files are persisted when I delete the pod.

When I do it in docker swarm I simply mount an empty NFS volume to /opt/myfiles/ and then my docker swarm service is started, the volume is populated with the files from the image and I can then work with my service and when I delete the service, I still have the files on my NFS server, so on next start of the service, I have my previous state back.

In kubernetes, when I mount an empty NFS volume to /opt/myfiles/, the pod is started and /opt/myfiles/ is overwritten with an empty directory, so my pod does not see the files from the image anymore.

My volme mount and volume definition:

```
[...]
volumeMounts:
  - name: myvol
    mountPath: /opt/myfiles
[...]
volumes:
  - name: myvol
    nfs:  
      server: nfs-server.mydomain.org
      path: /srv/shares/myfiles
```

I read some threads about similar problems (for example [K8s doesn't mount files on Persistent Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896056/k8s-doesnt-mount-files-on-persistent-volume)) and tried some stuff using `subPath` and `subPathExpr` as in the documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) but none of my changes does, what docker swarm does by default.

The behaviour of kubernetes seems strange to my as I have worked with docker swarm for quite a while now and I am familiar with the way docker swarm handles that. But I am sure that there is a reason why kubernetes handles that in another way and that there are some possibilities to get, what I need.

So please, can someone have a look at my problem and help me find a way to get the following behaviour?

- I have files in my image in some directory
- I want to mount an NFS volume to that directory, because I need to have the data persisted, when for example my pod crashes and moves to another host or when my pod is temporarily shut down for whatever reason.
- When my pod starts, I want the volume to be populated with the files from the image

And of course I would be really happy if someone could explain me, why kubernetes and docker swarm behave so different.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Your cluster is on local machine or cloud env? Could you show your YAMLs how you configured PV, PVC, Deployment/pods/Statefulset which one ar eyou using? What kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @PjoterS, we are using Kubernetes 1.19, not using PV / PVC, but nfs volumes (see my snippet). Cluster is runnig on local machines

Answer (score 6):

This can be usually achieved in Kubernetes with init-containers.
Let's have an image with files stored in `/mypath` folder. If you are able to reconfigure the container to use a different path (like `/persistent`) you can use init container to copy files from `/mypath` to `/persistent` on pod's startup.

```
containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: myimage
    env:
    - name: path
      value: /persistent 
    volumeMounts: 
    - name: myvolume
      path: /persistent
  initContainers:
  - name: copy-files
    image: myimage
    volumeMounts: 
    - name: myvolume
      path: /persistent
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp /mypath/*.* /persistent']
```

In this case you have a main container `myapp-container` using files from `/persistent` folder from the NFS volume and each time when container starts the files from  `/mypath` will be copied into that folder by init container `copy-files`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot so far. So you mean we could configure the container to use files from a directory that we mount as volume and copy some initial files from the image there with a initContainer (only if the files in the persistent / volume directory) do not exist? That should work (upvote) but compared to docker it sounds like a workaround to me. Before i accept this answer, I will wait, if someone comes with another (more straight forward) solution or an explanation, why kubernetes behaves like that.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Docker Swarm, but I can not imagine that mount allows you to combine files from the target folder and the mounted volume, unless you are mounting the volume as a sub folder (like `/mypath/persistent`) .
In general it make sense to separate configuration folder from the persistent data for k8s pods. Then you can use ConfigMaps for the configuration files and PV for persistent data.

Comment: When I mount an EMPTY volume in my docker swarm service to a directory with files in it, the files are transferred to the volume on container startup. For example. We have an image for an oracle database with a pre-created database in /opt/oracle/oradata. When I create an NFS volume pointing to an empty directory on the NFS fileserver and mount that directory to /opt/oracle/oardata in docker swarm, my container starts and I have the datafiles from the image in my volume. In kubernetes, my container fails to start, because the container only sees the empty /opt/oracle/oradata directory